# Function that runs on the opening of all Pages

Tags: android, flutter, dart

How can I write a function in flutter that works before opening it for all pages? For example, before I open all the pages I have created, I want to check if there is internet, free space on the device, charge status of the device is higher than x, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using a stateful widget, by overriding `initState()` method of a stateful widget, something like this -

```
class Example extends StatefulWidget {
  _ExampleState createState() => _ExampleState();
}
class _ExampleState extends State<Example> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    //Do your initialization stuff here
    super.initState();
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container();
  }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

## For a Stateless Page (widget)

You can call the function before returning you Page
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wf8ym.png)

## For a Stateful Page (widget)

You can call the function in the initState() method.
It will call this function exactly once before your page gets built.
(i.e. the build method gets called)
[For Stateful widgets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0OwFt.png)

I hope this is helpful.